# java generics instance variable bounded collection

Tags: java, generics

I have below example of Java Generics where I am trying to store a `processors` map which can store a `Processor` of its object. I have added a generic type for the `Processor` class. I want restrict the map `processors` to store only the it's key class' `Processor` object as it's value. Is there a way to use java wildcard or type bound on the `processors` collections? Please note that the the map itself can store multiple object of different classes in the key.

```
public class GenericsExample {

    private Map<?, Processor<?>> processors = new HashMap<>();

    public <O> void parameterisedMethod(O o) {
        processors.put(o, new Processor<O>());
    }

    static class Processor<T> {
        void process(T t) {
            System.out.println(t + " processed.");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no way to enforce that correspondence in the Java type system.  You can force the cast, but that's as good as you can get.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @LouisWasserman noted in his comment, you can't match the key and value types of a Map in java.

To implement this, you should use `Object` instead of wildcards for the key type in your map declaration:

```
private Map<Object, Processor<?>> processors = new HashMap<>();
```

The compiler will now let you insert any key with any associated processor in the map. It's your job to only allow matching types to be inserted:

```
<T> void addProcessor(T instance, Processor<? super T> processor) {
    processors.put(instance, processor);
}
```

To create the illusion of type-safety when reading from the map, you will need explicit casts; and perhaps some `@SuppressWarning("unchecked")` annotations. E.g.:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
<T> Processor<T> getProcessor(T instance) {
    return (Processor<T>) processors.get(instance);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a `ParamAndProcessor<T>` class to hold the parameter and its Processor together:

```
class ParamAndProcessor<T> {
  T param;
  Processor<T> processor;

  // Ctor.

  void process() {
    processor.process(param);
  }
}
```

Then store instances of this in the map:

```
Map<Object, ParamAndProcessor<?>> processors;

public void parameterisedMethod(Object o) {
  processors.put(o, new Processor<>());
}
```

If you want to put anything into `processors`, it can't have `?` as the key type.

Note that your `parameterizedMethod` doesn't actually need to be parameterized. (Nor does the `Processor` class, at least for what you've shown).